# Android Image resize (resample/downsample) before uploading

Tags: android, http, bitmap, resize

```
private void doFileUpload(){

    File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);

    String urlString = "http://example.com/upload_media_test.php";
    try
    {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
         FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);

         MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
         reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
         reqEntity.addPart("user", new StringBody("User"));
         post.setEntity(reqEntity);

         HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
         resEntity = response.getEntity();
         final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

         if (resEntity != null) {
             Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                         try {
                            res.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            res.setText("n Response from server : n " + response_str);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload Complete. Check the server uploads directory.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                       }
                });
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
         Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
  }
```

I get this code from internet. it's work but when I try upload bigger file than 1Mbyte,

I face an error with filesize.

I know how to resize bitmap images and but I have no idea upload the resized bitmap image.

how can I resize and upload with filebody?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a minor comment: you may not want to put a public http address that accepts data in your question here (just use http://example.com/my.php)

Comment: Also, for anyone with rep over 1500, I suggest tag `resample`, as this is different from resize and will help Googlers find this rather than the many resize questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to not only resize the Bitmap, but you also need to encode the result as a .jpg image. Therefore, you must open the file and convert it to a Bitmap, resize the Bitmap to a smaller image, encode the image into a byte[] array, and then upload the byte[] array in the same manner as you have uploaded your file `file1`.

If the Bitmap is large, which it clearly is, you won't have enough heap memory to open the entire thing, so you will have to open it with `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize`.

First, open the reduced size Bitmap:

```
Uri uri = getImageUri(selectedPath1);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4; // Example, there are also ways to calculate an optimal value.
InputStream in = in = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
```

Next, encode into a `byte[]` array:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, baos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
```

Finally, use `reqEntity.addPart()` to add the `byte[]` array directly, or write to a smaller file and add the file as in your current example.

Comment: Thanks David, However, I also have truble to upload image... :(

Comment: Voted up, but can you expand on `getImageUri` ? What object is that called on? Also, for multipart entities, would it sometimes make sense to convert the byte array back to a local file?

Comment: `getImageUri()` is a placeholder function for you to convert your `selectedPath1` variable into a `Uri`. I do not know the contents of `selectedPath1`. I believe you can convert directly like this: `Uri myUri = Uri.parse(selectedPath1);` Yes, it can be useful to save the `byte[]` array as a file and upload that. Makes it easier to use a stream, too. But, if the image is small enough, a byte array should work as well.

Comment: What would be the best way if there are multiple files? Because if we create a compressed byte[] array and add it to multipart request, it will eat out all memory.

Answer (score 0):

This answer [is based on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15535555/2615737), but I had some problems with that code, so I post the edited and working code.

I did it like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.outWidth = 50; //pixels
options.outHeight = 50; //pixels
InputStream in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData()); // here, you need to get your context.
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] bitmapdata = baos.toByteArray();
```

Notice that, *data* is the returned data from the Intent you use to get the file. If you already have the file path, just use that...

And now, when you are creating the HTTP Entity, add:

```
 FormBodyPart fbp = new FormBodyPart("image", new ByteArrayBody(baos.toByteArray(), "image/jpeg", "image"));
 entity.addPart(fbp);
```

Also, notice that you need a *MultipartEntity* to upload files.